# Travis CI build is failing to start upon modifying YAML file

Tags: yaml, travis-ci

Upon modifying my YAML file (see below) and initiating a push to GitHub, Travis CI does not want to start running the tests.

```
language: r
os: 
  - osx
  - linux

before_install: 
  - brew install llvm libomp
  - export CPP=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang

notifications:
  email:
   - never

branches:
  only:
   - master
```

I have run my YAML file through the YAML Lint checker:

http://www.yamllint.com

and the file checks as valid.

I have also updated and upgraded Homebrew, but the issue still persists.

Anyone know what might be the culprit here?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Are you sure that your YAML is valid?

Comment: @NicoHaase The YAML is now valid (I was missing an underscore in before_install). I have updated the post. Any ideas?

Comment: This could be a super good question if tuned into how to debug a travis YAML file before pushing it.

Comment: @Simson that would be answered pretty quickly: https://config.travis-ci.com/explore - if that does not complain about the file itself, there must be another reason for the pipelines not to start

Comment: @NicoHaase I have indeed used the Travis CI Build Config Explorer whose link you provide. My YAML file was parsed and validated successfully. However, for some strange reason, Travis still complains.